# How to Enable EnablePodIdentityPreview in C#?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli

In C#, I have coded a function to send API to send a [json body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) to azure which creates a managed aks cluster. But I get this errors.

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "PodSecurityPolicy is not allowed since feature \"Microsoft.ContainerService/PodSecurityPolicyPreview\" is not enabled. Please see https://aka.ms/aks/previews for how to enable features.",
  "subcode": ""
 }
```

In azure-cli, I do this but not sure how to do so in C#

```
az feature register --name EnablePodIdentityPreview --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService
az extension add --name aks-preview
az extension update --name aks-preview
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/features

Comment: Can you please provide me the code that to know where exactly it is blocking, and it will help us to know the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to send a POST to register the feature first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/features/register?tabs=HTTP